# 3 phase MWBC - 2 pole breaker with shared neutral

Tags: electrical, mwbc

I’ve searched around and can’t quite find an answer to my question.

I understand that you can share a neutral on a 3 phase panel if you use a 3 pole breaker. But can you still share a neutral on a 3 phase panel with a 2 pole breaker?

I wanted to create 2 separate 20amp outlets using 12/3 wiring. Black for outlet A and Red for outlet B, and share the neutral. Will this work as long as use a 2 pole 20amp breaker? Or will I run the risk of overloading the shared neutral?

Comment: Is this in a house or a commercial setting, and what make and model is your breaker box?

Comment: This is a commercial setting, but I don’t know the exact make and model of the breaker box. I can check in the next day or two. I do know that the breakers are Square D.

Comment: Carry on then -- were this residential, then AFCIs would be an issue because Square D 2-pole AFCIs aren't compatible with 208V power, but since you don't have AFCIs to worry about, you're good to go

Answer (score 3):

Think of it this way. What is the difference between a 2-phase MWBC on a 3-phase panel and a 3-phase MWBC with no load on one phase? Nothing.

I’d say that it is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can still share neutral. the worst case neutral current is still the same.

Comment: You mean in a worst case scenario, both hots maxed, neutral current = hot current but won't exceed it.

Comment: Just double checking… using 2 pole breaker on 3 phase/shared neutral should result in equal amps on both hots and shared neutral? (Assuming both hots are running the exact same amps)

Comment: Yes it will do that.